# What are the shogi equivalents of Fool's and Scholar's mate?

Tags: opening, checkmate, chess-variants, shogi, fools-mate

In western chess, the Fool's mate and Scholar's Mate are two well-known mates that take very few moves from the starting position.  What would be the shogi equivalents to these, or, more generally, what are the fastest checkmates in shogi?

Comment: In Xiangqi there is the famous 2 cannon mate (not that this helps you...)

Answer (score 11):

A very fast checkmate (6 moves) is described [here](http://81squareuniverse.heavenforum.org/t98-quick-checkmate#336):

```
1. P-7f P-8d 2. P-5f P-5d 3. R-5h S-4b 4. P-5e Px5e 5. Bx5e P-8e 6. Bx7c+ mate
```

[image: position after above moves]

<sub>apologies in advance for everyone who feels insulted because of the use of figurines instead of real Shogi pieces - I couldn't find another analysis board</sub>

Comment: Try lishogi.org so offensive to use this

Answer (score 7):

1. P-2f 2. K-4b 3. P-2e 4. K-3b 5. P-2d 6. R-4b 7. Px2c+ Checkmate

The King is trapped by his own Rook on 4b.
It's a bad idea to have the King and Rook close together or an early mate like this could happen in the worst case
[image]